# Setting up splash screen without white screen

Tags: android

I tried to setup a splash screen in my app using thi [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

I have a splash screen already in my android app. I have to show that screen instead of white screen. How can i do that?

Comment: I was able to achieve this following some research. The complete list of changes to achieve the same are noted at this gist. https://gist.github.com/midhunhk/fe2be8b80e4b9af15797d805045c88b4

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show something on your slpash screen then just add an InageView on the layout of your splash screen and set its layout bounds to match parent. Set the src attribute of the ImageView to the image you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

### Reason for white screen:

When a user launches an application, Android creates a new process that, during it charge, shows a black/white screen which is built with the application theme, or the theme of the activity that is the entry point.

This is know as **Cold start**.

### How to avoid white screen display:

You can simply use `android:windowBackground` attribute in Application theme style.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And set background value with `background_splash` having code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@color/grey"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/img_pizza"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Read more on avoiding cold starts and giving different animations http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts